# Vue.js Webpack | Using some imports only in development mode

Tags: javascript, css, import, webpack, vue.js

I'm using Webpack for building a vue.js application --> https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack

Now I wanna to import some css only in development mode. I want to import the scripts when running npm run start, but I wanna to exclude the scripts when I do a build with npm run build.

I could delete all the css imports before doing a npm run build, but is there a better solution?

Comment: Use `process.env.NODE_ENV` and create two different webpack configs. One for development and one for production. And add the webpack define plugin to use the environment variable in your files. Now you can check the for the environment and import different files.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one more thing to add:
In case you make an conditional import (using JS if statement and checking env variables), you can't use import statement. I've used require.

if (process.env["NODE_ENV"] === "development") {
 let myCss = require('./assets/fonts/fonts.css');
}